# Visual Studio 2012 Bookmarks

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

VS bookmarks are linked to specific lines of code until you save and reload your project, at which point they are linked to the original line # independent of the line of code. I wonder if anyone has a way of deleting and re-bookmarking all entries in one go while retaining the names? Or any other way to correct bookmark line numbers so they can be used again.

Resharper is a 3rd party package that is a solution but is kind of pricey.

EDIT: The VS team said they would not be fixing this bug. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/716222/bookmarks-not-always-staying-on-the-same-line

Comment: Can you please elaborate little more. Just save and reload the project should not make any changes to the bookmarks. What do you mean by 'reload' ? Is it, closing and opening the project once again or something else?

Comment: Try it out: bookmark line, delete a line above it, save/reload. Bookmark has moved down one line of code.

Comment: Reload: close and open the solution. The bookmarks even show the correct line numbers when you close it but they will change when you open the solution again.

Comment: yes, I got it. This is definitely a bug.